# unable to start program 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-4

Meu visual studio da noite pro dia começou a dar um erro ao iniciar a aplicação, esse erro só acontece na primeira vez que dou o start na aplicação (asp.net mvc 4), nas outras vezes o iis inicia e para na mesma hora

Erro:

> "unable to start program 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\iisexpress.exe'. Falha catastrófica"

Log do iis(dei espaço após todos os "http"s  para não formar link):

> ## Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
>
> ## Version: 1.0
>
> ## Date: 2017-01-10 00:39:07
>
> ## Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus
>
> sc-win32-status time-taken 2017-01-10 00:39:07 ::1 GET / - 62125 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   - 302 0 0 58598 2017-01-10 00:39:10 ::1 GET /Acesso/Login ReturnUrl=%2F 62125 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   - 200 0 0 2764 2017-01-10 00:39:10 ::1 GET /admin-lte/css/AdminLTE.css - 62125 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   http ://localhost:62125/Acesso/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F 200 0 0 120
>   2017-01-10 00:39:10 ::1 GET /Content/bootstrap.css - 62125 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   http ://localhost:62125/Acesso/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F 200 0 0 124
>   2017-01-10 00:39:10 ::1 GET /Images/logomarca1.png - 62125 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   http ://localhost:62125/Acesso/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F 200 0 0 19
>   2017-01-10 00:39:12 ::1 GET /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
>   - 62125 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   http ://localhost:62125/Content/bootstrap.css 200 0 0 27 2017-01-10
>   00:39:12 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 62125 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   http ://localhost:62125/Acesso/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F 200 0 0 9
>
> ## Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
>
> ## Version: 1.0
>
> ## Date: 2017-01-10 19:17:46
>
> ## Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus
>
> sc-win32-status time-taken 2017-01-10 19:17:45 ::1 GET / - 62125 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   - 302 0 0 18121 2017-01-10 19:17:49 ::1 GET /Acesso/Login ReturnUrl=%2F 62125 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   - 200 0 0 3574 2017-01-10 19:17:49 ::1 GET /Images/logomarca1.png - 62125 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   http ://localhost:62125/Acesso/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F 200 0 0 223
>   2017-01-10 19:17:50 ::1 GET /admin-lte/css/AdminLTE.css - 62125 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   http ://localhost:62125/Acesso/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F 200 0 0 723
>   2017-01-10 19:17:50 ::1 GET /Content/bootstrap.css - 62125 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   http ://localhost:62125/Acesso/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F 200 0 0 1097
>   2017-01-10 19:17:52 ::1 GET /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
>   - 62125 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/55.0.2883.87+Safari/537.36
>   http ://localhost:62125/Content/bootstrap.css 200 0 0 64

Comment: O erro ainda ocorre? O que você já tentou?
A reinstalação do VS2015 talvez resolva, já que ele reinstalará o iisexpress também.

Comment: já tentei reinstalar algumas vezes, reparar também n teve resultado.
o iis após uma terceira e última tentativa de reintalação funcionou, mas o graphic analyzer também deu problema, e de vez em quando ainda voltam os erros do iis, mas não é mais constante, ou seja meu vs2015 está bem instável